# Float32MultiArray in pub/sub example

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS people,

so basically, I am simply trying to reproduce a simple C++ pub/sub example using the Float32MultiArray type. Here are the codes :

**SUBSCRIBER**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h"
void subscriberCallback(const std_msgs::Float32MultiArray::ConstPtr& test)
{
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
    ROS_INFO("I heard %d: %f\n", i, test->data[i]);
}}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
 ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
 ros::NodeHandle n;
 ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("subscriber_topic", 1000, subscriberCallback);
 ros::spin();
 return 0;
 }
```

**PUBLISHER**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "publisher");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray>("subscriber_topic", 10);
ros::Rate rate(10);
while (ros::ok()){
std_msgs::Float32MultiArray data;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){data.data[i]=i;}
pub.publish(data);
ros::spinOnce();
rate.sleep();
}
return 0;
}
```

1- The catkin_make build gives no error at all.

2- If I launch the subscriber node and publish on the terminal to subscriber_topic F32MA data, everything goes fine, which means the problem is from the publisher side.

3- When launching the publisher node, here is the error (exit code -11 ? searched and didn't find anything around that) - couldn't put a screen -

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: melodic
* /rosversion: 1.14.13

NODES
/
publisher (publisher/publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[publisher-1]: started with pid [1332]
[publisher-1] process has died [pid 1332, exit code -11, cmd 
/home/lilialkalee/f32ma/devel/lib/publisher/publisher __name:=publisher 
__log:=/home/lilialkalee/.ros/log/ab233984-352b-11ee-accc-00155dae808d/publisher-1.log].
log file: /home/lilialkalee/.ros/log/ab233984-352b-11ee-accc-00155dae808d/publisher-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Btw, when I look for the log given with the path **/home/lilialkalee/.ros/log/ab233984-352b-11ee-accc-00155dae808d/publisher-1.log**, the publisher-1.log cannot be found xD

So, any clues ? and thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418216/float32multiarray-in-pub/sub-example/) by [Lilipop](https://answers.ros.org/users/149103/lilipop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2023-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2023-08-07**:
Here's an example that [does work](https://gist.github.com/jarvisschultz/7a886ed2714fac9f5226). I'm guessing your problem is that in this chunk `data.data[i]=i;` you have not told the computer that the `data.data` vector should have 5 entries. So you are trying to access uninitialized memory. You should likely be using something like `push_back` or `data.data.resize(5);` before your `for` loop in the publisher.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2023-08-07**:
If you look at the example above, you'll see that I use `push_back` on `Float32MultiArray.layout` to set the size of that vector, and then I use `std::vector::resize` to resize a vector that will contain the data I'm trying to publish (which I eventually set equal to `Float32MultiArray.data`).

Side note, I believe the `exit code -11` is coming from [Python's subprocess poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) function which, according to that link, would indicate your program exiting due to a signal 11.  Note, `roslaunch` is written in Python and uses the `subprocess` module to run nodes. [This would correspond](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to a `SIGSEGV` -- which is an invalid memory reference. This is consistent with my previous comment.

**Comment by [Lilipop](https://answers.ros.org/users/149103/lilipop/) on 2023-08-08**:
Hey, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. With the resize function now, I am able to get a functionning publisher !

Thanks again for your explanation :)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2023-08-09**:
Cool. I'm going to convert these to an answer so that this shows up as answered. If you wouldn't mind accepting that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example that [does work](https://gist.github.com/jarvisschultz/7a886ed2714fac9f5226). I'm guessing your problem is that in this chunk `data.data[i]=i;` you have not told the computer that the `data.data` vector should have 5 entries. So you are trying to access uninitialized memory. You should likely be using something like `push_back` or `data.data.resize(5);` before your `for` loop in the publisher.

If you look at the example above, you'll see that I use `push_back` on `Float32MultiArray.layout` to set the size of that vector, and then I use `std::vector::resize` to resize a vector that will contain the data I'm trying to publish (which I eventually set equal to `Float32MultiArray.data`).

Side note, I believe the `exit code -11` is coming from [Python's subprocess poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) function which, according to that link, would indicate your program exiting due to a signal 11.  Note, `roslaunch` is written in Python and uses the `subprocess` module to run nodes. [This would correspond](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to a `SIGSEGV` -- which is an invalid memory reference. This is consistent with my previous comment.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2023-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1